Dropdown Item - Change Colour On Hover - Of Variable Width Container
I have a dropdown navigation menu - but the widths of each dropdown-content are different depending on the length of words in each item. I want to fill the full width of each item on hover with a different colour. The width is not fixed. Using width : 100% does not work.
I Tried The Following Code. When I hover over an item in the dropdown-content to change the background colour the change in colour only happens around a particular item and not the full width of the dropdown-content menu. I cannot use a specific width for each item because they are of different widths. Setting the width to 100% does not work. Dropdown is the parent element - dropdown-content is the submenu. Each dropdown-content is of different widths.
**HTML Code **
`<ul>
<li class="dropdown"> 
<a href="#">Item</a>
<ul class="dropdown-content">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Text 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Text 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Text 1 Text 2 Text 3</a>
    </li>                                     
    <li>
        <a href="#">Text 5</a>
    </li>
                                   
</ul>
</li>
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#">Next item</a>
<ul class="dropdown-content">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Text 1 - Text 2 - Text 3 Text 4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Text 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Text 1</a>
    </li>                                     
    <li>
        <a href="#">Text 1 - Text 2 - Text 3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Text 44 - Text 55</a>
    </li>                                    
</ul>
</li>
</ul>


**CSS Code**

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown:hover a {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 600;
    background: #1A6AA9;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background: #1A6AA9;
    top: 64px;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    z-index: 1;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
    background: #1A6AA9;
    color: #ffffff;
    opacity: 0.8;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content li a:first-child {
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content li a {
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    font-weight: 500;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-content li {
    clear: left;
}

.dropdown-content li a:hover {
    background: green;
    width: 100%;
}`

